# Create shortcut in my own app

Tags: android, shortcut

I'm retrieving a list of available shortcuts like following:

```
public static ArrayList<PhoneAppItem> getInstalledShortcuts()
{
    PackageManager pm = MainApp.get().getPackageManager();
    ArrayList<PhoneAppItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    final Intent shortcutsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
    List<ResolveInfo> ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(shortcutsIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : ril)
    {
        PhoneAppItem item = new PhoneAppItem(ri.activityInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name);
        items.add(item);
    }
    Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<PhoneAppItem>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(PhoneAppItem ai1, PhoneAppItem ai2) {
            return ai1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(ai2.getName());
        }
    });

    return items;
}
```

Now I want the user to be able to create a custom shortcut in my app. Actually, I'm stuck here, I don't know what to do now... I know the package and activity, but there must be some shortcut setup...

**Question**

How can i create a shortcut (i.e. get the necessary data to start an intent and save it in my database)? To a contact for example... The contact app does offer shortcuts to all your contacts, how can I create on of those shortcuts in my app and use it?